# the relation between the lower limit of set and the lower limit of function

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

Define the characteristic function of set $A$ to be $${\chi _A}(x) = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&{x \in A}\\
0&{x \notin A}
\end{array}} \right..$$

For any given collection of sets ${A_n}$, how to prove
$$\mathop {\underline {\lim } }\limits_{n \to \infty } {\chi _{{A_n}}}(x) = {\chi _{\mathop {\underline {\lim } }\limits_{n \to \infty } {A_n}}}(x)$$
or in anothor words,
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n > 1} \mathop {\inf }\limits_{k \ge n} {\chi _{{A_k}}}(x) = {\chi _{\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n > 1} \bigcap\limits_{k = n}^\infty  {{A_k}} }}(x)$$
or in anothor words,
$$\mathop {\sup }\limits_{n > 1} \mathop {\inf }\limits_{k \ge n} {\chi _{{A_k}}}(x) = {\chi _{\bigcup\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\bigcap\limits_{k = n}^\infty  {{A_k}} } }}(x)$$

And some intuitive explanation behind this equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show that
$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty} \mathbf{1}_{A_k}(x) = \mathbf{1}_{\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n}(x), \qquad (\ast)
$$
where $\mathbf{1}_A$ denotes the characteristic function of the set $A$ and
$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} \bigcap_{k \geq n} A_k
$$
denotes the limit inferior of the sets $A_1$, $A_2$, ... . We have $x \in \bigcup_{n \geq 1} \bigcap_{k \geq n} A_k$ if and only if for some $n \geq 1$ we have $x \in \bigcap_{k \geq n} A_k$, hence for some $n \geq 1$ we should have $x \in A_k$ for all $k \geq n$. This is to say that $x$ is contained in all $A_k$ from some point onwards. Thus the right hand side of $(\ast)$ is $1$ if and only if $x$ is contained in all but finitely many of the $A_n$. The left hand side is the inferior limit of a sequence of $0$s and $1$s, so it takes the value $1$ if and only if the value $0$ occurs finitely many times (otherwise $0$ is a limit of a subsequence). Therefore, the left hand side is also $1$ if and only if all but finitely many of the $A_n$ contain $x$.

In the same spirit, we have
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} \mathbf{1}_{A_k}(x) = \mathbf{1}_{\limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n}(x), \qquad (\ast\ast)
$$
where
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n = \bigcap_{n \geq 1} \bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k.
$$
Both the left hand side and the right hand side of $(\ast\ast)$ are $1$ if and only if $x$ is contained in infinitely many of the $A_n$.