# Is there a way to relate lim sup/inf of sets to the definition for sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

For sequences of real numbers, it's defined as the least upper bound (sup)/greatest lower bound(inf).
For sequences of sets, it's defined as the set of elements that occur in infinitely many of the sets (sup)/all but finitely many of the sets(inf).

Is there a way to relate these two definitions, conceptually? I'm trying to think of a way to make it apparent that lim sup/inf is really just one concept, and not just two separate definitions for sets/sequences that have no relationship. So far, I've tried thinking of a vague "smallest bounding" set for sequence of sets.

The idea that lim inf of a sequence of sets is subset of the lim sup also throws me off, as it seems like there's no corresponding relationship in the definition for real sequences.

Comment: The definition for sets is the strict equivalent of the definition for real numbers, replacing the usual order on the real line by the order defined by inclusion between sets. The main difference is that this order is only partial (one can always compare real numbers, not always sets) but, apart from that, the supremum is the union and the infimum is the intersection, hence everything fits.

Comment: Some older posts which might help you:
[lim sup and lim inf of sequence of sets](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/107931),
[Interpretation of limsup-liminf of sets](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/172167),
[liminf and limsup with characteristic (indicator) function](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/72690),
[the relation between the lower limit of set and the lower limit of function](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1102132)